# What is the proper format of request for querying a report?

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, youtube-analytics-api

Good afternoon everyone! I need to get the `estimatedMinutesWatched` parameter from YouTube's Analytics API. I found some examples on the internet, for example [this one](https://issue.life/questions/20694736), and they all used the method:

```
$api = $analytics->reports->query($id, $start_date, $end_date, $metric, $optparams);
```

but now you need to pass a single array to the method, which is why I get errors.

I can't figure out which array should be passed to `query()`. This is my code:

```
 $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setClientId($clientID);
        $client->setClientSecret($clientSecret);
        $client->setRedirectUri($redirectUri);
        $client->addScope("email");
        $client->addScope("profile");

// authenticate code from Google OAuth Flow
        if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
            $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
            $client->setAccessToken($token);
            $start_date = '2000-01-01';
            $end_date = '2021-01-01';
            $metrics = 'estimatedMinutesWatched';
            $channel_url='https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqRTXU9O7v3KeJcQuxmEhaA';
            $ids = 'channel==' . $channel_url . '';
            $analytics = new Google_Service_YouTubeAnalytics($client);
            $optparams = array(
                'dimensions' => '7DayTotals',
                'sort' => 'day',
                'ids' => $ids,
                'start_date' => $start_date,
                'end_date' => $end_date,
                'metric'=>$metrics
            );
            $api = $analytics->reports->query($optparams);

            var_dump($api);
            die();
```

The exeption I've got is:

```
(query) unknown parameter: 'start_date'
```

I understand that I need to rewrite the query, but really don't know how to do that.

Comment: Remember YouTube analytics only has about 90 days worth of data last i checked.  Besides the fact that i dont think that YouTube was even around in '2000-01-01'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official doc of YouTube Analytics' [Reports Query](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query), the name of the date parameters are: [`startDate`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query#startDate) and [`endDate`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query#endDate) (notice the camel case).

Thus your API call should look like:

```
$analytics = new Google_Service_YouTubeAnalytics($client);
$optparams = array(
    'dimensions' => '7DayTotals',
    'sort' => 'day',
    'ids' => $ids,
    'startDate' => $start_date,
    'endDate' => $end_date,
    'metrics' => $metrics
);
$api = $analytics->reports->query($optparams);
```

I also corrected the `metric` parameter to [`metrics`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query#metrics).

Do note also that the [`ids`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query#ids) parameter should contain a specification of form `channel == CHANNEL_ID`, but yours is `channel == CHANNEL_URL`. Just replace that with:

`channel == UCqRTXU9O7v3KeJcQuxmEhaA` or `channel == MINE`.

As per the official doc, it is presumed that `UCqRTXU9O7v3KeJcQuxmEhaA` is the ID of the channel corresponding to the user that authorized your app during the OAuth 2.0 authentication/authorization flow.